# Nexus 7 Share Dialog No Longer Showing Up After KitKat

Tags: nexus-7, 4.4-kitkat, share-menu

Before the KitKat upgrade, tapping "Share" in apps would bring up a dialog that lists all apps that you can share to. After upgrading to KitKat, tapping this button only copies the link to the clipboard.

I should note that this only happens on some apps, like these listed below:

- Chrome
- Bacon Reader
- Hacker News 2
- Trello

Is there a way to bring back the old functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known bug with Kitkat, not only affecting the Nexus but other devices as well. We [discussed that on chat lately](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12380166#12380166). A work-around is using an app like [AppChooser](http://www.appbrain.com/app/AppChooser/jp.co.noxi.apppicker), which replaces the share menu. As a side-effect, it even gives you several improvements above the built-in share menu, as e.g. the possibility to chose between grid and list display, or have the list sorted alphabetically versus last-used (where the latter would have your most frequently used share-targets always on top). You can even hide apps you don't want to see in the share menu (and make them visible via the "show all" button).

[image: AppChooser] [image: AppChooser]
<sup>AppChoser (source: Google Play)</sup>

The only alternative I know of is [Andmade Share](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Andmade-Share/com.andmadesoft.share), which offers comparable features.